# Lost usb with wallet backups

Tags: wallet, litecoin, backup

I was hoping someone would be able to help please?!!

I backed up my litecoin core wallet and neo wallet to my usb- today i took that usb out with me since I had other stuff on it too and needed to use it. I lost the usb like an idiot- is there a way to change the seed for my neo wallet and address for litecoin wallet so if someone finds my usb, they can't get into the wallets. I know I have backed them up on the USB but I am not sure what other info I have left on there.

I know I am an idiot- please help this idiot!!

Answer (score 1):

If someone finds your USB and it has a full backup, they’ll be able to recreate your current wallets and steal all the funds. If you still have a working instance of those wallets, then you should immediately transfer all funds out of them and into new wallets. Do not use the original wallets to store funds ever again, create a brand new wallet (ie new seed) and use that from now on.

Be careful with your backups, if someone stole your coins you would likely have no recourse at this point.

Comment: Right, so what I have done is created new wallets and seeds for neon and on the litecoin core wallet I encrypted it and I got a message saying something like one previous backups will cease to work? is that right?

Comment: @Polyscript unless encryption involves your wallet sending a tx to move all coins to a new address, I don’t think it would be sufficient (I am unsure of exactly how litecoin core works in this regard). In general, I would just create a new wallet and transfer your coins to it. Then you will for sure be safe against someone finding the USB

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to simply create a new wallet for each, and transfer your coins to it. The seed is easy to change, but anyone with the old seed can still access the old wallets, so you should cease to use them immediately.

Ideally, don't keep backups on a drive you carry regularly with you. Instead, either store them on paper or a USB that you can safely lock away. Even better, get a hardware wallet.

Comment: Right, so what I have done is created new wallets and seeds for neon and on the litecoin core wallet I encrypted it and I got a message saying something like one previous backups will cease to work? is that right?

Comment: Yes, naturally. If you recreate the wallets, they have no relation to any previous back up you made, since the keys have changed.